# Update application install by another appleID

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, macos

I use a mac install before by another user. This user install some application like Xcode with this appleID.

Now this user not use this computer and I want update application he install before. I have my own AppleID. when I ask to update application the system say me I can't do that because this application was install by another appleID.

How I can uninstall this application to install with my own AppleId or update this application with my own AppleID ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just moving the application bundles to trash in Finder? If that doesn't work or you want to remove the support files as well, removing applications from Launchpad (by clicking the cross icons shown while holding option) should remove other files as well.

Comment: You right, when I push application on trash this application is remove and I can reinstall it. Thanks